# Installing Yarn on Windows 10 : Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\aymer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn'

Tags: windows, npm, yarnpkg

On Windows 10, running:

```
npm install --global yarn
```

creates

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\aymer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\aymer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn'
```

From other posts, I have tried:

- running this as administrator but still the same error, any idea?
- `npm cache clean --force`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I eventually installed it with the msi file...